# Линейный массив в иерархический JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть линейный массив:

```
var arr = [
   {"name11":"item11", "name12":"item12"},
   {"name21":"item21", "name22":"item22"},
   {"name31":"item31", "name32":"item32"},
]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать его в иерархический?

```
var arr = [{
    "name11":"item11", 
    "name12":"item12", 
    "name13":[{
        "name21":"item21", 
        "name22":"item22", 
        "name23":[
            {"name31":"item31", "name32":"item32"},
        ]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Есть какой-то алгоритм. по которому преобразовывать нужно? Всегда ли нужно "разворачивать" именно третий?

Comment: Да, всегда разворачивается третий элемент.

Comment: И все массивы в результате всегда содержат лишь один объект?

Comment: К каждому элементу массива(объекту), добавляется в конец новый элемент и в него вкладываются все последующие существующие элементы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
let src = [
   {"name11":"item11", "name12":"item12"},
   {"name21":"item21", "name22":"item22"},
   {"name31":"item31", "name32":"item32"},
];
let cursor = src[0]; // сохраняем ссылку на текущий элемент

// Проходим по всем объектам, кроме первого
for (let i = 1; i < src.length; ++i) {
  // Генерируем ключ для нового элемента (name13)
  let key = 'name'+i+(Object.keys(cursor).length + 1);
  // Вставляем ссылку на объект завёрнутый в массив в нужное место    
  cursor[key] = [src[i]];
  // Удаляем на старом месте(в массиве образуется дырка)
  delete src[i];
  // Обновляем курсор, чтобы работать со следующим уровнем
  cursor = cursor[key][0];
};
src.length = 1; // Обрезаем образовавшиеся дырки

console.log(src);
```